Writing a bootable ISO to USB with other partitions
So say I have a flash drive with GPT on it with several partitions in that order:

Data (16GB ExFat)
Kali Linux live (4GB ext4)
Kali persistence (4GB ext4)

The first partition is offset from the start by ~8700 MB. My question is:
Will I be able to use the free unpartitioned space at the start to write and boot an ISO image (some Linux/Windows installer maybe that is smaller than 8GB) and be sure it won't corrupt the partitions and files on them after the first ~8GB?
Does it depend on the method used (e.g. dd vs GUI tools) or the ISO itself?
My plan is to simply backup the GPT with gdisk to a file and then restore it once I'm done (installing the OS) with that ISO file.
The flash drive in question is SanDisk Extreme, so it's more like a small SSD.

Many tools don't directly write the image but repartition the target disk and extract only the contents of the image. Those can easily destroy existing data.
"Direct write" tools (e.g. dd, not those which extract and rearrange the image's contents like Rufus) will only write as much as the image file contains. So the partitions' data should remain intact. Test first.
However, if you just restore the old partition table using sfdisk, the new image's contents won't be able to boot. You'll need to merge the partition tables, appending the original partitions after the ones that the image has brought with itself.
Beware that some images aren't purely read-only: for example, the ones meant to be written to RPi SD cards as a full installation (as opposed to live boot images) are often set up to automatically resize their root partition to fill the rest of the disk on first boot.
Also note that not all .iso images are automatically bootable from USB disks – it's primarily a CD/DVD image (different sector size, different location of the boot code) and there's no requirement for them to be made into hybrid images. Windows ISOs do not have a MBR or GPT, for example; they have to be manually extracted to a partition.

"repartition the target disk and extract only the contents of the image".
It's not a problem as long as they write to the start of the disk at block level (where free space is). Is that not guaranteed?

"So the partitions' data should remain intact" It will not. GParted shows the whole disk as ISO after dd. But I don't really care as long as I can restore with gdisk after I'm done using the ISO, which I can. The question is, are all the files on restored partitions still intact because all those partitions come after the place where dd (or other tool) wrote?

That's what "the partitions' data" literally is...

Files are filesystem data though, not partition data? Partition data is start/end etc. My theory was that as long as the tool writes at the start (most obvious behavior), then even destroying partitions stored in the GPT (at the start and end of the disk) is not a problem (since we can just restore GPT backup).
